# pandas pivot_table percentile / quantile

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Is it possible to use percentile or quantile as the aggfunc in a pandas pivot table?  I've tried both numpy.percentile and pandas quantile without success.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dummy data:

```
In [135]: df = pd.DataFrame([['a',2,3],
                             ['a',5,6],
                             ['a',7,8], 
                             ['b',9,10], 
                             ['b',11,12], 
                             ['b',13,14]], columns=list('abc'))
```

`np.percentile` seems to work just fine?

```
In [140]: df.pivot_table(columns='a', aggfunc=lambda x: np.percentile(x, 50))
Out[140]: 
a  a   b
b  5  11
c  6  12
```

Comment: Thanks so much chrisb!  I was trying to us it directly without putting it in a lambda function.

Comment: This was a great solution until today. the above solution no longer works (but when I use 'mean', 'max', etc, it does work).  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: What version are you on?  IIRC some numpy stuff broke in `0.18.0`, but was fixed in `0.18.1`.

Answer (score 0):

The lambda function solutions works, but produces column names of "<lambda_0>" , etc. which need to be renamed later.

Instead of using a lambda (i.e. unnamed function), we could alternatively define our own functions. They should operate on a Series of values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a',2,3],
                   ['a',5,6],
                   ['a',7,8], 
                   ['b',9,10], 
                   ['b',11,12], 
                   ['b',13,14]], columns=list('abc'))
```

```
def quantile_25(growth_vals:pd.Series):
    return growth_vals.quantile(.25)

def quantile_75(growth_vals:pd.Series):
    return growth_vals.quantile(.75)


df.pivot_table(columns='a', aggfunc=[quantile_25, np.median, quantile_75])
```

The resulting column names will correspond with the function names.